# AttributeError: 'handDetector' object has no attribute 'hands'

Tags: python, opencv, mediapipe

I was trying to write the hand tracking module program using opencv and mediapipe, but encountered this error. Can someone help me with this? I am using opencv version: 4.6.0.66 , mediapipe version: 0.8.11 , and python version: 3.7

```
import cv2
import mediapipe as mp
import time


class handDetector():
    def init(self, mode=False, maxHands=2, modelC=1, detectionCon=0.5, trackCon=0.5):
        self.mode = mode
        self.maxHands = maxHands
        self.modelC = modelC
        self.detectionCon = detectionCon
        self.trackCon = trackCon

        self.mpHands = mp.solutions.hands
        self.hands = self.mpHands.Hands()
        self.mpDraw = mp.solutions.drawing_utils

    def findHands(self, img, draw=True):
        imgRGB = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        result = self.hands.process(imgRGB)
        #print(result.multi_hand_landmarks)
        if result.multi_hand_landmarks:
            for handLms in self.result.multi_hand_landmarks:
                if draw:
                    self.mpDraw.draw_landmarks(img, handLms, self.mpHands.HAND_CONNECTIONS)
        return img


def main():
    ctime = 0;
    ptime = 0;
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    detector = handDetector()
    while True:
        success, img = cap.read()
        img = detector.findHands(img)


        ctime = time.time()
        fps = 1 / (ctime - ptime)
        ptime = ctime

        cv2.putText(img, str(int(fps)), (10, 70), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 3, (255, 255, 255), 3)
        cv2.imshow("Image", img)
        cv2.waitKey(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I encountered this error. It says that the hands attribute is not a part of the handDetector class:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ritessshhh/PycharmProjects/handtracking/main.py", line 48, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/ritessshhh/PycharmProjects/handtracking/main.py", line 36, in main
    img = detector.findHands(img)
  File "/Users/ritessshhh/PycharmProjects/handtracking/main.py", line 20, in findHands
    result = self.hands.process(imgRGB)
AttributeError: 'handDetector' object has no attribute 'hands'
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python, the default constructor is named `__init__` (not `init`). Try renaming your `handDetector` class constructor to `__init__`.

(Also, it may be a good idea to rename the `handDetector` class to `HandDetector` in order to distinguish it, a `ClassName`, from a `regularVariable`.)

Answer (score 0):

`def init(self, mode=False, maxHands=2, modelC=1, detectionCon=0.5, trackCon=0.5):` 
this Should be

```
`def __init__(self, mode=False, maxHands=2, modelC=1, detectionCon=0.5, trackCon=0.5):`
```

Correct it and it will work.!

Have a Nice day.